# UWP Page Transition Animations

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp

I programing in Windows 10 UWP.
I have a Frame in Xaml that I would like to have the Page/Content to slide left and off screen when the use navigates away from the page to another page. Any Idea how to do Frame Navigation Animations?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to use build-in animation:

```
protected virtual void SetUpPageAnimation()
{
    TransitionCollection collection = new TransitionCollection();
    NavigationThemeTransition theme = new NavigationThemeTransition();

    var info = new ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo();

    theme.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo = info;
    collection.Add(theme);
    this.Transitions = collection;
}
```

Call this method in Page's `constructor` and you will find that there will be animation when you enter or leave a `Page`.

There are few build-in animations which names end with `Info`, you should try them by yourself.

Comment: odd.  i tried the xaml equivalent of this, and it just crashes the emulator.  but this did work!

Comment: Adding the transition in XAML should work. But make sure you did it exactly what the code above did, and it must crash for some reasons.

Comment: Good answer, but lacks of a bit more explanation and a link to the docs...

Answer (score 1):

There's a built-in way to do this, but that only supports a set of not customizable animations / page transitions.

If you want to do custom animations you'll need to implement your own Frame + Page subclasses, where your Pages contain their own entrance/leaving animations and your Frame calls these when navigating.