# Transitions (i.e. EntranceThemeTransition) doesn't work in UWP

Tags: windows, xaml, animation, win-universal-app, transition

I am trying to apply EntranceThemeTransition on a button but it doesn't seem to work. I didn't get any error and the app runs fine but without the transitions.

Here's my code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App9.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App9"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
  <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Content="Hello World" Click="Button_Click">
      <Button.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
          <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="100" IsStaggeringEnabled="True"/>
        </TransitionCollection>
      </Button.Transitions>
    </Button>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518493/entrancethemetransition-not-working-on-uwp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579445/uwp-page-transition-animations). But it still doesnt work.

Update: The following code works on my home PC. I tried to reset all the settings in VS2015 and still didn't work. It looks like there's something that messed up my environment. I need help from anyone who encountered the same problem.

Comment: I test your code, it works. I think your `EntranceThemeTransition` is not clear to see, cause the `FromHorizontalOffset` vaule is large enough. Please set it to 2000, and test it again.

Comment: I also haven't any problem with your code. All works good.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it in my PC at home and it's working fine too. Maybe there's something in the settings of my work PC. I'll try to restore the VS2015 settings.

Comment: Maybe on your PC Transitions disabled? check it
http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/windows-10-tip-disable-desktop-animations

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I know the answer. It's not Visual Studio, it's in the System Settings. I went to System Settings.

1. Win + X
2. click System
3. click Advanced System Settings
4. On the Advanced tab, go to performance section then click Settings
5. Check "Animate controls and elements inside windows"
6. Click Apply button.

[image]